# SPE Object reference not set to an instance of an object

Tags: powershell-extensions

In Sitecore 9.02 I get this error running any script in Powershell ISE. Console works fine.

Stack trace:

```
[NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.]
   Cognifide.PowerShell.Core.Settings.c__DisplayClass88_0.b__0(ItemEditArgs p) +402
   Cognifide.PowerShell.Core.Extensions.ItemExtensions.Edit(Item item, Action`1 action) +688
   Cognifide.PowerShell.Core.Settings.ApplicationSettings.Save() +277
   Cognifide.PowerShell.Client.Applications.PowerShellIse.JobExecuteScript(ClientPipelineArgs args, String scriptToExecute, ScriptSession scriptSession, Boolean autoDispose, Boolean debug) +1793
   Cognifide.PowerShell.Client.Applications.PowerShellIse.JobExecuteScript(ClientPipelineArgs args, String scriptToExecute, Boolean debug) +1252
   Cognifide.PowerShell.Client.Applications.PowerShellIse.Debug(ClientPipelineArgs args) +199
```

Comment: oh, btw happens in both SPE 4.7.2 and 5.0

Comment: Are you running the script as an admin?

Comment: Yes, even the default admin doesn't work.

Comment: Weird thing is that with the same application and database (basically a copy of my local one) it is working on a test server. Guess it must be something in a recent Win 10 update... confusing.

Comment: In the end I got it working by restoring the back-up from the testserver-databases. Obviously something got corrupted in my database.