# Get-ItemReferrer : Object reference not set to an instance of an object

Tags: powershell-extensions

I am working on Sitecore PowerShell Extensions 5.0.0.42513 with Sitecore 9.0.
I have started facing issue as `Get-ItemReferrer : Object reference not set to an instance of an object`

Also shown below in screenshot :-

[image]

Complete stack trace is as follows :-

```
Get-ItemReferrer : Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
At C:\inetpub\wwwroot\sc901.local\temp\tmp7605.ps1:3 char:19
+ ... ringItems = Get-ItemReferrer -Id "{C674D9DF-B5EA-4F3B-8871-F80B2F214F ...
+                 ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
+ CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Get-ItemReferrer], NullReferenceException
+ FullyQualifiedErrorId : System.NullReferenceException,Cognifide.PowerShell.Commandlets.Data.GetItemReferrerCommand
```

Point to be noticed here is that this script was working fine on Sitecore 8 with Sitecore PowerShell Extensions-4.7.2 for Sitecore 8.

Now I have upgraded my local instance to Sitecore 9.0.1 and Sitecore PowerShell Extensions 5.0.0.42513 and now getting this error.

I have also gone through with the link [SPE Object reference not set to an instance of an object](https://sitecore.stackexchange.com/questions/15484/spe-object-reference-not-set-to-an-instance-of-an-object)

I have also tried to execute few basic commands (which are working fine) to be sure that setup is not corrupted.

Not sure if `Get-ItemReferrer` has been deprecated, if yes then what is the alternative for this.

Any pointer in this regard is highly appreciated.

Update 1 :- Below is the script for reference.

```
$workflowStateID = Get-Item -Path master: -ID "{C674D9DF-B5EA-4F3B-8871-F80B2F214F28}"
$referringItems = Get-ItemReferrer -Item $workflowStateID | Where-Object { $_.__Updated -gt [datetime]::Now.AddDays(-30) -and $_.__Created -gt [datetime]::Now.AddDays(-30)}

#EmptyArray
$listofWorkflowItems = @()

#$listofWorkflowItems

#Skip System Items
Foreach($item in $referringItems) { 

    $itemPaths = $item.Paths.FullPath
    if($item.Paths.FullPath.contains('/sitecore/content/abc-website'))
    {
        $rendering = $item | Get-Rendering

        $addInList = New-Object System.Object
        $addInList | Add-Member -type NoteProperty -name ID -Value $item.ID
        $addInList | Add-Member -type NoteProperty -name Path -Value $item.FullPath
        $addInList | Add-Member -type NoteProperty -name ItemCreateDate -Value $item.Created

        if($item.'__Never publish' -eq 1)
        {
            $addInList | Add-Member -type NoteProperty -name Publishable -Value 'True'
        }
        else{
            $addInList | Add-Member -type NoteProperty -name Publishable -Value 'False'
        }       

        $workflowdetailList = Get-ItemWorkflowEvent -Id $item.ID | Where-Object { $_.NewState -eq '{C674D9DF-B5EA-4F3B-8871-F80B2F214F28}' } | Sort-Object -Property Date -Descending

        Foreach($workflow in $workflowdetailList){
                $addInList | Add-Member -type NoteProperty -name WorkflowApprover -Value $workflow.User
                $addInList | Add-Member -type NoteProperty -name ApprovedDate -Value $workflow.Date
                break
        }

        if($rendering){
            $addInList | Add-Member -type NoteProperty -name URL -Value $item.FullPath.Replace("/sitecore/content/abc-website/home","https://abc.com") 
        }

        $listofWorkflowItems += $addInList
    }
}
$listofWorkflowItems | Show-ListView
```

Comment: Can you please share the script you are executing and also make sure that you have rebuild the link database and that the item id you are searching exists

Comment: Can you rebuild your link database? Does the issue continue?

Comment: @HishaamNamooya I have updated the question with the script. Kindly refer. I have checked the item id and it exists. I am facing issue in rebuilding link database. Below is the error stack trace :-                                                     
Object reference not set to an instance of an object. [NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.]   Sitecore.Shell.Applications.Dialogs.RebuildLinkDatabase.RebuildLinkDatabaseForm.CheckStatus() +201
[TargetInvocationException: Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation.]

Comment: @MichaelWest I tried rebuilding link database and I am getting error on this step. Object reference not set to an instance of an object. [NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.] Sitecore.Shell.Applications.Dialogs.RebuildLinkDatabase.RebuildLinkDatabaseForm.CheckStatus() +201 [TargetInvocationException: Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation.]

Comment: Then I suspect the issue has more to do with that than it does SPE.

Answer (score -1):

I was getting the "Object reference not set to an instance of an object" error for Update-ItemReferrer. I was able to resolve it by rebuilding the links database. I'm using Sitecore 10.2.